# What's the meaning of JavaScript in below?

Tags: javascript

`l = (m, n) => { if (w()) return n-1;}` is one of a sample code but I want to understand the use of this in a JavaScript I have a long code which has most use of these elements can anyone help me out on this really confused on this part.

I have tried on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp but could not get exact answers.

I have tried on some forums too but the exact search results could not be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

`=>` stands for [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which was introduced in ES6.

So instead of typing below syntax for writing function:

```js
function test(m, n) {
    if (w()) return n-1;
}
```

The same can be written using arrow function:

```js
(m, n) => {
    if (w()) return n-1;
}
```

In your code snippet, variable `l` is assigned the value of above function. 
Your function will return `n-1` based on the return of another function `w()`.